# C++ library issue

Tags: c#, c++, c

I'm trying to make a call to a C++ library from my C# code. I also have a sample application written in C++ that invokes the same library, and works fine. However, the call from C# throws an error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The c# code is:

```
#region DllImports

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(int hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(int hModule);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate string bondProbeCalc(string licenseFolder, string requestString);

#endregion


/// <summary>
/// Calls Bondprobe to calculate a formula
/// </summary>
internal static string DoBondProbeOperation(string requestString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestString)) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    //Reference library
    int hModule = LoadLibrary(ConfigurationManager.Instance.BondProbeSettings.AssemblyFilePath);

    if (hModule != 0)
    {
        IntPtr intPtr = GetProcAddress(hModule, "bpStringCalc");

        bondProbeCalc funcDelegate = (bondProbeCalc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(intPtr, typeof(bondProbeCalc));

        requestString = requestString.EndsWith("=") ? requestString.Substring(0, requestString.Length - 1) : requestString;

        string returnValue = funcDelegate(ConfigurationManager.Instance.BondProbeSettings.LicenseFilePath, requestString);

        FreeLibrary(hModule);

        return returnValue;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

This exact same code works on some computers, and it throws the error on others. However, the sample C++ app seems to work everywhere.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Gonzalo

Comment: I recommend using `IntPtr` instead of `int` (for all pointers, this includes the return type from LoadLibrary)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Exactly which function causes the crash?  All of them?

Comment: @Sam Skuce Not sure what you mean, i'm just calling one function in the c++ assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the crashing is occurring on computers running 64-bit OSs. I don't know about your `DoBondProbeOperation` logic, but your PInvoke methods should be defined as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll"]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll"]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Where you compare `hModule` to `0`, instead compare to `IntPtr.Zero`

EDIT: Fixed `CharSet` value for `LoadLibrary`

EDIT2: Also try changing your `bondProbeCalc` definition to the following:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
delegate string bondProbeCalc(string licenseFolder, string requestString);
```

Or:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string bondProbeCalc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string licenseFolder, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string requestString);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Here's the signature for the c++ function:

extern char *bpStringCalc(char *bpDirectory, char *issString);

Comment: @Gonzalo If the native function is indeed C++ rather than C, then the lack of `extern "C"` in that signature would imply that the functions exported name is in fact not `bpStringCalc`, but rather some mangled name. Is the native code actually C, or did you omit the `extern "C"` when pasting the signature here?

Comment: @Gonzalo I've edited my post with a few suggestions regarding your `bondProbeCalc` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

[Comments on `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) indicate that calling conventions other than Stdcall are not supported, i.e. that specifying `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` on your delegate type is not effective. If this is indeed the case, you'll need to switch to using PInvoke to call `bpStringCalc`, recompile the native library to export the function with the `__stdcall` modifier, or write a shim in C++/CLI (as IJW interop would not have this calling convention restriction).

Comment: As I recall, the x64 CLR has automatic stack correction for marshaled function calls with mismatched Cdecl/Stdcall calling conventions; the x86 CLR does not. So, it may be the case that the computers experiencing crashes are running x86 OSs. In any case, your PInvoke signatures were **definitely** wrong before and should be corrected, even if doing so has no apparent effect.